# GPS coordinates not updated every time

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi, android-gps

I'm using SIM808 to get GPS coordinates. I'm fetching GPS data every 10 seconds. But I'm getting the same GPS coordinate 2-3 times. AT command (CGPSINF) does not yield a new coordinate on every call, so I get repeatedly the same coordinate.

Please help me out why I'm not getting updated GPS coordinate on every AT command call. Previously I was working on Ublox GPS receiver, same things happened there. That module also sent repeated coordinates when I was using this with a Python library on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: what does the NMEA data show?

Answer (score 0):

There will be some data stored in buffer in serial. You have to flush it before you read the data.
Suppose your serial port is defined like this:

```
ab= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
```

So before reading data flush the buffer.

```
ab.flush()
```

Then read the data from it.

```
ab.readline()
```